# Конвертирование миллисекунд в секунды с плавающей точкой

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть переменная, содержащая значение в миллисекундах `let ms = 300;`, как можно сконвертировать миллисекунды в секунды с плавающей точкой и как регулировать количество знаков после запятой? Например, чтобы можно было выводить `0.3 сек.` или `0.300 сек.`?

Comment: нужно разделить на 1000, функция [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) позволяет задать количество знаков после запятой

Comment: @Grundy спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Пример метода перевода миллисекунд в секунды:

```js
function millisToSeconds(millis) {
      // toFixed(3) вернет 0.300; toFixed(1) вернет 0.3
      var seconds = (millis / 1000).toFixed(3);
      return seconds + ' сек.';
}

var seconds = millisToSeconds(300); 
alert(seconds); // результатом будет 0.300 сек.
```

> Метод [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) форматирует число, используя запись с фиксированной
>   запятой.

---

Кстати, к слову, вот неплохой пример конвертирования миллисекунд в минуты и секунды:

```
function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
  var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
  return minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
}

millisToMinutesAndSeconds(298999); // "4:59"
millisToMinutesAndSeconds(60999);  // "1:01"
```

Ссылка на источник: [Converting milliseconds to minutes and seconds with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294619/5275890)